# gremlinpython - How do you select(keys) in a graph_traversal?

Tags: python, gremlin

In this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55963311/gremlinpython-return-id-and-label-as-string/55976545#55976545) a suggestion was made to use the query supplied in the first answer to do a particular gremlin_python traversal. Namely

```
g.V().has('name', 'USA').limit(1000).hasLabel('Country').
  map(union(project('id','label').
              by(id).
              by(label),
            valueMap()).unfold().
      group().
        by(keys).
        by(select(values)))
```

I am able to import all but "keys" from the gremlin_python graph traversal library like the following

```
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import union, project, valueMap, select, key, values, id, label, map
```

Looking at the [gremlin_python](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-python/src/main/jython/gremlin_python/process/graph_traversal.py) repo, I don't see a way to define the portion that is "by(keys)"

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keys` and `values` in that context should import from the `Column` enum - in the source code [here](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/dfbb88c7cb8a8d16df2ec025f2cb3932e4991695/gremlin-python/src/main/jython/gremlin_python/process/traversal.py#L134-L137). Note the full list of recommended imports in the [Reference Documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#python-imports).